# JVM crash with SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000090000

Tags: crash, jvm, fatal-error, segmentation-fault

We faced an issue on server where the JVM crashed and seems like most threads been in blocked state.
I dont think it is GC which is causing it since also the GC daemon is blocked.

From the GC info, does not seems like memory issue.. and there are no errors in the `/var/log/messages` file.

Unfortunately, even when it is saying that a core dump written, there is no core file on the server. no storage issue or so.

Any help is more than welcome :)

I will paste the `hs_err_pid` file below.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
    #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000090000, pid=10320, tid=140491055642368
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_66-b17) (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.66-b17 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000090000
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /opt/CSCOlumos/core or core.10320
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007fc5a0f60000):  JavaThread "http-nio-443-exec-39" daemon [_thread_in_Java, id=1520, stack(0x00007fc69f6f3000,0x00007fc69f774000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000090000

Registers:
RAX=0x00007fc754276be0, RBX=0x00007fc5ef526f68, RCX=0x0000000000000006, RDX=0x00007fcb0ea9e188
RSP=0x00007fc69f770bc0, RBP=0x0000000000000007, RSI=0x00007fcb0ea9e188, RDI=0x00007fc69f770b40
R8 =0x0000000000090000, R9 =0x00007fcb0358d000, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x00007fcb18a69600
R12=0x00007fc5b9f27f20, R13=0x00007fc754276be0, R14=0x00007fc69f770820, R15=0x00007fc5a0f60000
RIP=0x0000000000090000, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000014
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007fc69f770bc0)
0x00007fc69f770bc0:   00007fc754274938 00007fc7542727d8
0x00007fc69f770bd0:   00007fc7542727d8 00007fcb18c6e1e9
0x00007fc69f770be0:   00007fc5a0f60000 00007fcb0d642ef8
0x00007fc69f770bf0:   00007fc5a0f60000 00007fcb035949b0
0x00007fc69f770c00:   00007fc69f770c68 00007fcb03594670
0x00007fc69f770c10:   00007fcb03594670 00007fc754274938
0x00007fc69f770c20:   00007fc7542727d8 00007fc69f770c28
0x00007fc69f770c30:   00007fc5daf2d079 00007fc69f770c98
0x00007fc69f770c40:   00007fc5daf2d838 00007fc5b7d11e80
0x00007fc69f770c50:   00007fc5daf2d108 00007fc69f770c18
0x00007fc69f770c60:   00007fc69f770c90 00007fc69f770ce0
0x00007fc69f770c70:   00007fcb035949b0 0000000000000000
0x00007fc69f770c80:   00007fc754274938 00007fc7542748e0
0x00007fc69f770c90:   0000000000001000 00007fc7542727d8
0x00007fc69f770ca0:   00007fc69f770ca0 00007fc5daf2cecc
0x00007fc69f770cb0:   00007fc69f770d10 00007fc5daf2d838
0x00007fc69f770cc0:   00007fc5b7d11ce8 00007fc5daf2cf20
0x00007fc69f770cd0:   00007fc69f770c90 00007fc69f770d00
0x00007fc69f770ce0:   00007fc69f770d58 00007fcb035949b0
0x00007fc69f770cf0:   00007fc7542727d8 0000000000000000
0x00007fc69f770d00:   00007fc84956a4b8 0000000000001000
0x00007fc69f770d10:   00007fc754251018 00007fc69f770d18
0x00007fc69f770d20:   00007fc5daf2cd35 00007fc69f770d70
0x00007fc69f770d30:   00007fc5daf2d838 00007fc5b7d123e0
0x00007fc69f770d40:   00007fc5daf2cd60 00007fc69f770d00
0x00007fc69f770d50:   00007fc69f770d68 00007fc69f770db8
0x00007fc69f770d60:   00007fcb035949b0 00007fc84956a4b8
0x00007fc69f770d70:   00007fc754251018 00007fc69f770d78
0x00007fc69f770d80:   00007fc5f4ff6819 00007fc69f770df8
0x00007fc69f770d90:   00007fc5f4ff6e18 00007fc5b7d11aa8
0x00007fc69f770da0:   00007fc5f4ff6888 00007fc69f770d68
0x00007fc69f770db0:   00007fc69f770e00 00007fc75426fd60 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000000090000)
0x000000000008ffe0:   
[error occurred during error reporting (printing registers, top of stack, instructions near pc), id 0xb]

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=
[error occurred during error reporting (printing register info), id 0xb]

Stack: [0x00007fc69f6f3000,0x00007fc69f774000],  sp=0x00007fc69f770bc0,  free space=502k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x0000000000090000
```

Answer (score -1):

```
---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00007fcaf4cba000 JavaThread "http-nio-443-exec-49" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6679, stack(0x00007fc5d2bdc000,0x00007fc5d2c5d000)]
  0x00007fcafdac8800 JavaThread "http-nio-443-exec-48" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6652, stack(0x00007fc5eca18000,0x00007fc5eca99000)]
  0x00007fcaf4bfd000 JavaThread "http-nio-443-exec-47" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6651, stack(0x00007fc5ed3ab000,0x00007fc5ed42c000)]
  0x00000000051ac000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6338, stack(0x00007fc5bc73c000,0x00007fc5bc7bd000)]
  0x00007fcaf5299800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6337, stack(0x00007fc5ef870000,0x00007fc5ef8f1000)]
  0x00007fc6c1a3c800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6336, stack(0x00007fc5ca167000,0x00007fc5ca1e8000)]
  0x00007fc57cd80800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6329, stack(0x00007fc5d2ada000,0x00007fc5d2b5b000)]
  0x00007fc6c1acf000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6328, stack(0x00007fc69ebd9000,0x00007fc69ec5a000)]
  0x00007fc6c112b000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6327, stack(0x00007fc5e1731000,0x00007fc5e17b2000)]
  0x00007fc5a0e34800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6326, stack(0x00007fc5e1833000,0x00007fc5e18b4000)]
  0x00007fc5a5eac000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6325, stack(0x00007fc5bcd4c000,0x00007fc5bcdcd000)]
  0x0000000007616800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6324, stack(0x00007fc5ebe00000,0x00007fc5ebe81000)]
  0x0000000001b5c800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6323, stack(0x00007fc5d9803000,0x00007fc5d9884000)]
  0x00007fc5a5e68000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6322, stack(0x00007fc69f351000,0x00007fc69f3d2000)]
  0x00007fcaf5d5e800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6321, stack(0x00007fc5bb1c2000,0x00007fc5bb243000)]
  0x0000000005d12000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6320, stack(0x00007fc5bbf30000,0x00007fc5bbfb1000)]
  0x0000000002b45000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6319, stack(0x00007fc5d18b7000,0x00007fc5d1938000)]
  0x00000000015f6000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6318, stack(0x00007fc69e9d5000,0x00007fc69ea56000)]
  0x00007fc5d404b800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6317, stack(0x00007fc5b9a1e000,0x00007fc5b9a9f000)]
  0x0000000001f93000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6316, stack(0x00007fc5b8171000,0x00007fc5b81f2000)]
  0x00000000040c7000 JavaThread "WebSocket background processing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6315, stack(0x00007fc5bb2c4000,0x00007fc5bb345000)]
  0x00007fcafe0d2800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6314, stack(0x00007fc5ebafa000,0x00007fc5ebb7b000)]
  0x00007fcafd073000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6313, stack(0x00007fc69eb58000,0x00007fc69ebd9000)]
  0x00007fcafc535000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-2023" [_thread_blocked, id=6312, stack(0x00007fc5e4a9b000,0x00007fc5e4b1c000)]
  0x0000000000a0a000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6311, stack(0x00007fc5c9eef000,0x00007fc5c9f70000)]
  0x00007fcaf4562000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6310, stack(0x00007fc69f1ec000,0x00007fc69f26d000)]
  0x00007fc6c3e3a000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6309, stack(0x00007fc68eb8a000,0x00007fc68ec0b000)]
  0x00007fcaf408f000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6308, stack(0x00007fc5ed932000,0x00007fc5ed9b3000)]
  0x0000000003518800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6307, stack(0x00007fc5e1b39000,0x00007fc5e1bba000)]
  0x00007fcaf6414000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6306, stack(0x00007fc5ca6ff000,0x00007fc5ca780000)]
  0x00007fc6c2d72000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6305, stack(0x00007fc5cd9a2000,0x00007fc5cda23000)]
  0x00007fcafdb80800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6303, stack(0x00007fc5ea1c8000,0x00007fc5ea249000)]
  0x00007fc6c0b93800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6302, stack(0x00007fc5e2cdc000,0x00007fc5e2d5d000)]
  0x00007fc6c3f14000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6301, stack(0x00007fc5cd71d000,0x00007fc5cd79e000)]
  0x00007fc5a2a76000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6300, stack(0x00007fc5bb924000,0x00007fc5bb9a5000)]
  0x00007fcafeaf6000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6299, stack(0x00007fc5f0688000,0x00007fc5f0709000)]
  0x00000000068c9000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6298, stack(0x00007fc5c9ff1000,0x00007fc5ca072000)]
  0x00000000073ee000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6297, stack(0x00007fc5d25ac000,0x00007fc5d262d000)]
  0x00007fcafca4e800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6296, stack(0x00007fc69e8e2000,0x00007fc69e963000)]
  0x00007fc6992e1800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6295, stack(0x00007fc5e2e5f000,0x00007fc5e2ee0000)]
  0x0000000004417800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6294, stack(0x00007fc5bbe2e000,0x00007fc5bbeaf000)]
  0x00000000096a1000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29735" [_thread_blocked, id=6293, stack(0x00007fc5bb3c6000,0x00007fc5bb447000)]
  0x0000000001b6e000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29736" [_thread_blocked, id=6292, stack(0x00007fc5e1e3f000,0x00007fc5e1ec0000)]
  0x00007fcafea3b800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29736" [_thread_blocked, id=6291, stack(0x00007fc5d2046000,0x00007fc5d20c7000)]
  0x00000000084f4000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-29737" [_thread_blocked, id=6290, stack(0x00007fc5ccf8e000,0x00007fc5cd00f000)]
  0x00007fcafc785000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-15029" [_thread_blocked, id=6289, stack(0x00007fc68b3ae000,0x00007fc68b42f000)]
  0x00007fc5a5eff800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-6045" [_thread_blocked, id=6285, stack(0x00007fc5d14b3000,0x00007fc5d1534000)]
  0x00007fc597cb3800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-6045" [_thread_blocked, id=6284, stack(0x00007fc5ee6d1000,0x00007fc5ee752000)]
  0x0000000005c90800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-6045" [_thread_blocked, id=6283, stack(0x00007fc5bbeaf000,0x00007fc5bbf30000)]
  0x00007fc5a1a88800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-6045" [_thread_blocked, id=6282, stack(0x00007fc5e1ec0000,0x00007fc5e1f41000)]
  0x00007fc672b3c800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-6045" [_thread_blocked, id=6281, stack(0x00007fc5e16b0000,0x00007fc5e1731000)]
  0x00007fc69964e800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-6045" [_thread_blocked, id=6280, stack(0x00007fc5d272f000,0x00007fc5d27b0000)]
  0x0000000000bb1000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-6045" [_thread_blocked, id=6279, stack(0x00007fc590343000,0x00007fc5903c4000)]
  0x00007fcaf7135000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-6045" [_thread_blocked, id=6278, stack(0x00007fc5bad39000,0x00007fc5badba000)]
  0x00007fc6c0b05800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-6045" [_thread_blocked, id=6277, stack(0x00007fc5e2853000,0x00007fc5e28d4000)]
  0x00007fc57d5dd000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-6045" [_thread_blocked, id=6276, stack(0x00007fc69ee5c000,0x00007fc69eedd000)]
  0x00007fc6c3c8b000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-6045" [_thread_blocked, id=6275, stack(0x00007fc5ccc88000,0x00007fc5ccd09000)]
  0x00007fc59d124000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-6045" [_thread_blocked, id=6274, stack(0x00007fc69fb70000,0x00007fc69fbf1000)]
  0x00007fcaf6a93000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-6045" [_thread_blocked, id=6246, stack(0x00007fc69f3d2000,0x00007fc69f453000)]
  0x0000000001248000 JavaThread "ActiveMQ BrokerService[ServiceDiscoveryNotificationBroker] Task-50495" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6245, stack(0x00007fc5e3b7d000,0x00007fc5e3bfe000)]
  0x00000000097d8000 JavaThread "ActiveMQ BrokerService[XMP_Message_Broker] Task-26689" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6244, stack(0x00007fc5bb03f000,0x00007fc5bb0c0000)]
  0x00007fcafc700800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-6045" [_thread_blocked, id=6243, stack(0x00007fc69ea56000,0x00007fc69ead7000)]
  0x0000000000b98800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-6045" [_thread_blocked, id=6242, stack(0x00007fc5ca67e000,0x00007fc5ca6ff000)]
  0x0000000004254000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-6045" [_thread_blocked, id=6241, stack(0x00007fc5bb8a3000,0x00007fc5bb924000)]
  0x00007fc5a63d6000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-6045" [_thread_blocked, id=6240, stack(0x00007fc5df36e000,0x00007fc5df3ef000)]
  0x00007fcaf5be3800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-6045" [_thread_blocked, id=6239, stack(0x00007fc5bcccb000,0x00007fc5bcd4c000)]
  0x0000000006274000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-6045" [_thread_blocked, id=6238, stack(0x00007fc5d12af000,0x00007fc5d1330000)]
  0x0000000001033000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-6045" [_thread_blocked, id=6237, stack(0x00007fc5d9884000,0x00007fc5d9905000)]
  0x0000000002240800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-6045" [_thread_blocked, id=6236, stack(0x00007fc5f6206000,0x00007fc5f6287000)]
  0x00007fc5d5abe800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-6045" [_thread_blocked, id=6235, stack(0x00007fc5bb141000,0x00007fc5bb1c2000)]
  0x0000000001a90000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-6045" [_thread_blocked, id=6234, stack(0x00007fc69faef000,0x00007fc69fb70000)]
  0x00007fcafe8a3000 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-6045" [_thread_blocked, id=6233, stack(0x00007fc677dfb000,0x00007fc677e7c000)]
  0x00007fcafc880800 JavaThread "seqtaskexecutor-6045" [_thread_blocked, id=6232, stack(0x00007fc5bb69f000,0x00007fc5bb720000)]
  0x0000000001cda800 JavaThread "ActiveMQ BrokerService[ServiceDiscoveryNotificationBroker] Task-50494" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6087, stack(0x00007fc5cce8c000,0x00007fc5ccf0d000)]
  0x000000000651d000 JavaThread "ActiveMQ BrokerService[ServiceDiscoveryNotificationBroker] Task-50491" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5690, stack(0x00007fc5da640000,0x00007fc5da6c1000)]
  0x00000000072f3000 JavaThread "ActiveMQ BrokerService[ServiceDiscoveryNotificationBroker] Task-50489" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5454, stack(0x00007fc5e2dde000,0x00007fc5e2e5f000)]
  0x0000000001fc3000 JavaThread "ActiveMQ BrokerService[ServiceDiscoveryNotificationBroker] Task-50487" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5292, stack(0x00007fc69f5b8000,0x00007fc69f639000)]
  0x0000000000b52800 JavaThread "ActiveMQ BrokerService[ServiceDiscoveryNotificationBroker] Task-50468" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1532, stack(0x00007fc69f97b000,0x00007fc69f9fc000)]
  0x00007fcaf4d7a000 JavaThread "http-nio-443-exec-46" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28551, stack(0x00007fc5d9e90000,0x00007fc5d9f11000)]
  0x00007fcaf61a5800 JavaThread "http-nio-443-exec-44" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28550, stack(0x00007fc69fd80000,0x00007fc69fe01000)]
  0x00007fc6c1596000 JavaThread "ActiveMQ Transport: ssl:///127.0.0.1:15452" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4056, stack(0x00007fc5bd2d3000,0x00007fc5bd354000)]
  0x00007fc698b9d000 JavaThread "ActiveMQ Transport: ssl://localhost/127.0.0.1:61617" [_thread_in_native, id=4055, stack(0x00007fc5b7752000,0x00007fc5b77d3000)]
  0x00007fcaf5f8b800 JavaThread "TQ-Publisher - 6" [_thread_blocked, id=24797, stack(0x00007fc5ccd09000,0x00007fc5ccd8a000)]
  0x0000000006615800 JavaThread "allTriggeredJobsExecutor-26" [_thread_blocked, id=722, stack(0x00007fc5e1ab8000,0x00007fc5e1b39000)]
  0x00007fcafe822800 JavaThread "http-nio-443-exec-42" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6188, stack(0x00007fc5cd417000,0x00007fc5cd498000)]
=>0x00007fc5a0f60000 JavaThread "http-nio-443-exec-39" daemon [_thread_in_Java, id=1520, stack(0x00007fc69f6f3000,0x00007fc69f774000)]
  0x00007fcaf575a800 JavaThread "http-nio-443-exec-36" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7400, stack(0x00007fc593265000,0x00007fc5932e6000)]
  0x00007fcafeffb800 JavaThread "http-nio-443-exec-35" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7340, stack(0x00007fc5b48f2000,0x00007fc5b4973000)]
  0x00007fc5a2b04000 JavaThread "pool-68-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=26240, stack(0x00007fc5bb243000,0x00007fc5bb2c4000)]
  0x00007fc6c35ad800 JavaThread "pool-32-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=19944, stack(0x00007fc5aa257000,0x00007fc5aa2d8000)]
  0x00007fc59f4e2000 JavaThread "CDBPool-OpticalDwdm15-thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=1631, stack(0x00007fc5d1d40000,0x00007fc5d1dc1000)]
  0x00007fc5a4400000 JavaThread "CDBPool-OpticalDwdm15-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=30974, stack(0x00007fc5b940e000,0x00007fc5b948f000)]
  0x0000000009636800 JavaThread "CDBPool-OpticalDwdm15-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=30596, stack(0x00007fc5eab5b000,0x00007fc5eabdc000)]
  0x00007fcaf46b4800 JavaThread "CDBPool-OpticalDwdm15-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=27729, stack(0x00007fc5bd1d1000,0x00007fc5bd252000)]
  0x00007fcafcbc2000 JavaThread "Thread-1508" [_thread_blocked, id=11679, stack(0x00007fc5d1ec3000,0x00007fc5d1f44000)]
  0x00000000017f1800 JavaThread "OnDemandWiredClientPoller" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11349, stack(0x00007fc5e1f41000,0x00007fc5e1fc2000)]
  0x00007fcaf578a000 JavaThread "ActiveMQ Data File Writer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3770, stack(0x00007fc5b930c000,0x00007fc5b938d000)]
  0x00000000030df000 JavaThread "CorrIsoThread_DuplicateEventSuppresion_t0" [_thread_blocked, id=3413, stack(0x00007fc5b64a9000,0x00007fc5b652a000)]
  0x00007fc698dc6800 JavaThread "CorrIsoThread_AnyAlarmFlapping_t0" [_thread_blocked, id=3412, stack(0x00007fc5bc03b000,0x00007fc5bc0bc000)]
  0x00007fc59e66a800 JavaThread "ICE Service - CPU 39" [_thread_blocked, id=900, stack(0x00007fc5d2a59000,0x00007fc5d2ada000)]
  0x00007fc5a48b5800 JavaThread "ICE Service - CPU 38" [_thread_blocked, id=32103, stack(0x00007fc5eda38000,0x00007fc5edab9000)]
  0x00007fc5a4ed2800 JavaThread "ICE Service - CPU 37" [_thread_blocked, id=31722, stack(0x00007fc5cd921000,0x00007fc5cd9a2000)]
  0x00007fc6c21a1800 JavaThread "ICE Service - CPU 36" [_thread_blocked, id=31486, stack(0x00007fc5bc0bc000,0x00007fc5bc13d000)]
  0x00007fcafec9c800 JavaThread "ICE Service - CPU 35" [_thread_blocked, id=30882, stack(0x00007fc5b6830000,0x00007fc5b68b1000)]
  0x00007fcafc235000 JavaThread "ICE Service - CPU 34" [_thread_blocked, id=30726, stack(0x00007fc5e2f65000,0x00007fc5e2fe6000)]
  0x00007fcafdbcf800 JavaThread "ICE Service - CPU 33" [_thread_blocked, id=30686, stack(0x00007fc5d9986000,0x00007fc5d9a07000)]
  0x00007fc6c38ae800 JavaThread "ICE Service - CPU 32" [_thread_blocked, id=29962, stack(0x00007fc5cd8a0000,0x00007fc5cd921000)]
  0x00007fc6700bc800 JavaThread "ICE Service - CPU 31" [_thread_blocked, id=28867, stack(0x00007fc5b66ad000,0x00007fc5b672e000)]
  0x0000000006277800 JavaThread "ICE Service - CPU 30" [_thread_blocked, id=28562, stack(0x00007fc5cd090000,0x00007fc5cd111000)]
  0x00007fc6997ee800 JavaThread "ICE Service - CPU 29" [_thread_blocked, id=28151, stack(0x00007fc5cd519000,0x00007fc5cd59a000)]
  0x00007fcaf659b000 JavaThread "ICE Service - CPU 28" [_thread_blocked, id=27996, stack(0x00007fc5cd00f000,0x00007fc5cd090000)]
  0x00007fcafdbd1000 JavaThread "configParallelExecutor-10" [_thread_blocked, id=27986, stack(0x00007fc5d122e000,0x00007fc5d12af000)]
  0x00007fc698a00800 JavaThread "detectingDetailSyncUp" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=27454, stack(0x00007fc5f0e9c000,0x00007fc5f0f1d000)]
  0x00007fcaf705e000 JavaThread "refreshRogueAp" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=27453, stack(0x00007fc5ed72e000,0x00007fc5ed7af000)]
  0x00007fcaf4ccd800 JavaThread "deleteDetectingDetail" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=27452, stack(0x00007fc5b4f7f000,0x00007fc5b5000000)]
  0x00007fc586328000 JavaThread "RemoveFromIgnoreList" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=27451, stack(0x00007fc5b73c7000,0x00007fc5b7448000)]
  0x00007fc5a2576000 JavaThread "DiscoverRogues" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=27450, stack(0x00007fc5e3877000,0x00007fc5e38f8000)]
  0x0000000007b78800 JavaThread "RogueDataProcessor" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=27449, stack(0x00007fc5d90f5000,0x00007fc5d9176000)]
  0x00007fc69925f000 JavaThread "RoguePoller1" [_thread_blocked, id=27448, stack(0x00007fc5d1534000,0x00007fc5d15b5000)]
  0x00007fcaf79d7000 JavaThread "ICE Service - CPU 27" [_thread_blocked, id=27065, stack(0x00007fc5b4dfc000,0x00007fc5b4e7d000)]
  0x00007fcaf7070000 JavaThread "configParallelExecutor-9" [_thread_blocked, id=27063, stack(0x00007fc5b7a54000,0x00007fc5b7ad5000)]
  0x00007fcafc1f4000 JavaThread "ICE Service - CPU 26" [_thread_blocked, id=27018, stack(0x00007fc5b6d3a000,0x00007fc5b6dbb000)]
  0x00007fcaf6db6800 JavaThread "configParallelExecutor-8" [_thread_blocked, id=27009, stack(0x00007fc5ad19d000,0x00007fc5ad21e000)]
  0x00007fc594a6f000 JavaThread "http-nio-443-exec-33" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=26803, stack(0x00007fc5da844000,0x00007fc5da8c5000)]
  0x00007fc5a3d18000 JavaThread "http-nio-443-exec-26" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=26796, stack(0x00007fc5b43e8000,0x00007fc5b4469000)]
  0x00007fc699653000 JavaThread "http-nio-443-exec-14" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=26741, stack(0x00007fc5b44ea000,0x00007fc5b456b000)]
  0x0000000003b2b000 JavaThread "ICE Service - CPU 25" [_thread_blocked, id=26649, stack(0x00007fc5b60a1000,0x00007fc5b6122000)]
  0x00007fc6c3920000 JavaThread "configParallelExecutor-7" [_thread_blocked, id=26648, stack(0x00007fc5ea4ce000,0x00007fc5ea54f000)]
  0x00007fcafceca000 JavaThread "ThreadManager-ConfigArchive-20" [_thread_blocked, id=26637, stack(0x00007fc5edd4d000,0x00007fc5edd86000)]
  0x00007fcaff4c0000 JavaThread "ICE Service - CPU 24" [_thread_blocked, id=26635, stack(0x00007fc5af23f000,0x00007fc5af2c0000)]
  0x00007fc6c2a20800 JavaThread "configParallelExecutor-6" [_thread_blocked, id=26625, stack(0x00007fc5b5891000,0x00007fc5b5912000)]
  0x00007fc5a5cae000 JavaThread "ThreadManager-ConfigArchive-19" [_thread_blocked, id=25596, stack(0x00007fc5eed21000,0x00007fc5eed5a000)]
  0x00007fc5a5f42800 JavaThread "ICE Service - CPU 23" [_thread_blocked, id=25595, stack(0x00007fc5b5b16000,0x00007fc5b5b97000)]
  0x00007fc6c33f3000 JavaThread "configParallelExecutor-5" [_thread_blocked, id=25589, stack(0x00007fc5b79d3000,0x00007fc5b7a54000)]
  0x00007fc5a4a7b800 JavaThread "ThreadManager-ConfigArchive-18" [_thread_blocked, id=25506, stack(0x00007fc5eece8000,0x00007fc5eed21000)]
  0x0000000001654000 JavaThread "ICE Service - CPU 22" [_thread_blocked, id=25505, stack(0x00007fc5d27b0000,0x00007fc5d2831000)]
  0x00007fcafe242800 JavaThread "configParallelExecutor-4" [_thread_blocked, id=25496, stack(0x00007fc5b5000000,0x00007fc5b5081000)]
  0x00007fc5d5a90800 JavaThread "ThreadManager-ConfigArchive-17" [_thread_blocked, id=24495, stack(0x00007fc5f089f000,0x00007fc5f08d8000)]
  0x00007fc6988ae000 JavaThread "ICE Service - CPU 21" [_thread_blocked, id=24494, stack(0x00007fc5b71c3000,0x00007fc5b7244000)]
  0x00007fc6c0a9a000 JavaThread "configParallelExecutor-3" [_thread_blocked, id=24483, stack(0x00007fc5ad6a7000,0x00007fc5ad728000)]
  0x00007fc5a521d800 JavaThread "ThreadManager-ConfigArchive-16" [_thread_blocked, id=23793, stack(0x00007fc5f5d90000,0x00007fc5f5dc9000)]
  0x00007fc6c31fc000 JavaThread "ICE Service - CPU 20" [_thread_blocked, id=23792, stack(0x00007fc5b6326000,0x00007fc5b63a7000)]
  0x00007fc6c3df5000 JavaThread "configParallelExecutor-2" [_thread_blocked, id=23783, stack(0x00007fc5b6cb9000,0x00007fc5b6d3a000)]
  0x00007fcaf6ea7000 JavaThread "http-nio-443-exec-12" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23630, stack(0x00007fc5b6e3c000,0x00007fc5b6ebd000)]
  0x00007fcafcd40000 JavaThread "ThreadManager-ConfigArchive-15" [_thread_blocked, id=23499, stack(0x00007fc5f5dc9000,0x00007fc5f5e02000)]
  0x00007fc6c3bce800 JavaThread "ICE Service - CPU 19" [_thread_blocked, id=23497, stack(0x00007fc5b754a000,0x00007fc5b75cb000)]
  0x00007fcafd531000 JavaThread "CorrIsoThread_tl1_granular_inventory_rule_t0" [_thread_blocked, id=23475, stack(0x00007fc5b5993000,0x00007fc5b5a14000)]
  0x00007fcaf5934000 JavaThread "configParallelExecutor-1" [_thread_blocked, id=23473, stack(0x00007fc5b5912000,0x00007fc5b5993000)]
  0x00007fcafd374000 JavaThread "pool-69-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=16655, stack(0x00007fc5b6c38000,0x00007fc5b6cb9000)]
  0x00007fcafd6f5000 JavaThread "pool-69-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=16654, stack(0x00007fc5d2c5d000,0x00007fc5d2cde000)]
  0x00007fcaf7928800 JavaThread "pool-69-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=16653, stack(0x00007fc5b6dbb000,0x00007fc5b6e3c000)]
  0x00007fc6c1a6c000 JavaThread "pool-70-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=16201, stack(0x00007fc5ad09b000,0x00007fc5ad11c000)]
  0x00007fc6cd815800 JavaThread "pool-70-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=16200, stack(0x00007fc5af0bc000,0x00007fc5af13d000)]
  0x00007fcafc70f800 JavaThread "pool-70-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=16199, stack(0x00007fc5bb822000,0x00007fc5bb8a3000)]
  0x00007fcafea57000 JavaThread "CDBPool-DVAVAILABILITY-thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=15970, stack(0x00007fc5da111000,0x00007fc5da192000)]
  0x00007fc6c2538800 JavaThread "CDBPool-ENVTEMP-thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=15966, stack(0x00007fc5bca46000,0x00007fc5bcac7000)]
  0x00007fc670770800 JavaThread "CleanAirAlarmAnalyzer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15763, stack(0x00007fc5b568d000,0x00007fc5b570e000)]
  0x0000000001ced800 JavaThread "CDBPool-DVAVAILABILITY-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=15629, stack(0x00007fc5ace97000,0x00007fc5acf18000)]
  0x00007fcaf4571000 JavaThread "CDBPool-ENVTEMP-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=15625, stack(0x00007fc5b7142000,0x00007fc5b71c3000)]
  0x00007fcaf4664800 JavaThread "pool-61-thread-25" [_thread_blocked, id=14848, stack(0x00007fc5e2043000,0x00007fc5e20c4000)]
  0x00007fcaf4ab2800 JavaThread "pool-61-thread-24" [_thread_blocked, id=14843, stack(0x00007fc5b42e6000,0x00007fc5b4367000)]
  0x00007fcaf4aba000 JavaThread "pool-61-thread-23" [_thread_blocked, id=14838, stack(0x00007fc5ad626000,0x00007fc5ad6a7000)]
  0x00007fcaf7087800 JavaThread "pool-61-thread-22" [_thread_blocked, id=14836, stack(0x00007fc5bb7a1000,0x00007fc5bb822000)]
  0x00007fcaf534e000 JavaThread "pool-61-thread-21" [_thread_blocked, id=14798, stack(0x00007fc5d2957000,0x00007fc5d29d8000)]
  0x00007fc6cd52f000 JavaThread "CDBPool-DVAVAILABILITY-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=14790, stack(0x00007fc5b3fe0000,0x00007fc5b4061000)]
  0x0000000006c1f000 JavaThread "CDBPool-ENVTEMP-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=14786, stack(0x00007fc5b5d9b000,0x00007fc5b5e1c000)]
  0x00007fcaf60ea000 JavaThread "pool-61-thread-20" [_thread_blocked, id=14724, stack(0x00007fc5bbfb1000,0x00007fc5bc032000)]
  0x00007fcaf60bd000 JavaThread "pool-61-thread-19" [_thread_blocked, id=14643, stack(0x00007fc5ada2e000,0x00007fc5adaaf000)]
  0x00007fcaf72bf000 JavaThread "pool-61-thread-18" [_thread_blocked, id=14614, stack(0x00007fc5b18ce000,0x00007fc5b194f000)]
  0x00007fcaf508b000 JavaThread "pool-61-thread-17" [_thread_blocked, id=14613, stack(0x00007fc5af13d000,0x00007fc5af1be000)]
  0x00007fc6983cb000 JavaThread "pool-61-thread-16" [_thread_blocked, id=14611, stack(0x00007fc5aef39000,0x00007fc5aefba000)]
  0x00007fcafcb7d000 JavaThread "ThreadManager-ConfigArchive-14" [_thread_blocked, id=14610, stack(0x00007fc5ace25000,0x00007fc5ace5e000)]
  0x00007fcaf5ffa800 JavaThread "pool-61-thread-15" [_thread_blocked, id=14599, stack(0x00007fc5b1a51000,0x00007fc5b1ad2000)]
  0x00007fcaf5d55000 JavaThread "pool-61-thread-14" [_thread_blocked, id=14594, stack(0x00007fc5b47f0000,0x00007fc5b4871000)]
  0x00007fcaffc59000 JavaThread "ThreadManager-ConfigArchive-13" [_thread_blocked, id=14520, stack(0x00007fc5bc9c5000,0x00007fc5bca46000)]
  0x00007fcafcb7d800 JavaThread "ThreadManager-ConfigArchive-12" [_thread_blocked, id=14405, stack(0x00007fc5af341000,0x00007fc5af3c2000)]
  0x00007fcaf7240000 JavaThread "pool-61-thread-13" [_thread_blocked, id=14328, stack(0x00007fc5b184d000,0x00007fc5b18ce000)]
  0x00007fcaf46b3800 JavaThread "pool-61-thread-12" [_thread_blocked, id=14289, stack(0x00007fc5aeeb8000,0x00007fc5aef39000)]
  0x00000000096c9800 JavaThread "ICE Service - CPU 18" [_thread_blocked, id=14283, stack(0x00007fc5ca780000,0x00007fc5ca801000)]
  0x00007fcaf4157800 JavaThread "pool-61-thread-11" [_thread_blocked, id=14257, stack(0x00007fc5e1d3d000,0x00007fc5e1dbe000)]
  0x00000000096c8000 JavaThread "ICE Service - CPU 17" [_thread_blocked, id=14227, stack(0x00007fc5af1be000,0x00007fc5af23f000)]
  0x00007fcaf46b5000 JavaThread "pool-61-thread-10" [_thread_blocked, id=14226, stack(0x00007fc5b1ad2000,0x00007fc5b1b53000)]
  0x00007fcaf4059800 JavaThread "pool-61-thread-9" [_thread_blocked, id=14225, stack(0x00007fc5af2c0000,0x00007fc5af341000)]
  0x00007fcaf5f7d000 JavaThread "pool-61-thread-8" [_thread_blocked, id=14219, stack(0x00007fc5bb0c0000,0x00007fc5bb141000)]
  0x00007fcaf6c92800 JavaThread "pool-61-thread-7" [_thread_blocked, id=14181, stack(0x00007fc5b5f1e000,0x00007fc5b5f9f000)]
  0x00007fcaf4f50000 JavaThread "pool-61-thread-6" [_thread_blocked, id=13929, stack(0x00007fc5ef366000,0x00007fc5ef3e7000)]
```